# Vue-Router doesn't work in a Select Option

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, html-select, router

I I try to create a simple navigation from a select option but without results.
`<router-link>` does not work inside `<select><option>`

Here's what I tried :

**vue**

```
  <div>
    <select v-model="selected">
      <option v-for="orga in organisations" :key="orga.name">
        <router-link :to="{name: 'Box', params: {orga: orga.route}}">
          {{ orga.name }}
        </router-link>
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

**javascript**

```
  data() {
    return {
      selected: this.$route.params.orga,
      organisations: [
        { name: "Abc", route: "abc" },
        { name: "Lmn", route: "lmn" },
        { name: "Xyz", route: "xyz" }
      ]
    };
  }
```

Comment: Do you have the named route "Box" already present?

Comment: thank you, yes it works perfectly without the select option. I have 'Box' for the name and /:orga in the path

Comment: You can call another function on the event: @change, to redirect the user programatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your view based on the `select` option, you can't use a `router-link` inside an option tag.

However, you can achieve this by a workaround shown below. Here we will be switching the views based on the `select` option and changing the route.

```js
Vue.component('compA', {
  template: '<div>{{name}}</div>',
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'Component A'
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('compB', {
  template: '<div>{{name}}</div>',
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'Component B'
    }
  }
})

const routes = [{
    path: '/a',
    component: {
      template: '<compA/>'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/b',
    component: {
      template: '<compB/>'
    }
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      selected: ''
    }
  },
  router,
  methods: {
    routeChange: function(e) {
      this.$router.push(e.target.value)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <select @change="routeChange">
      <option></option>
      <option v-for="(c, i) in ['a', 'b']" :key="i">
        {{ c }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <router-view/>
</div>
```

But this scenario can be alternatively achieved by dynamic components. The [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components) explains more about this which can be used to switch between components or dynamic render.

```js
Vue.component('CompA', {
  template: '<div>new component A</div>'
})

Vue.component('CompB', {
  template: '<div>new component B</div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      value: ""
    }
  },
  template: `
  <div>
  <select v-model="value">
    <option v-for="c in ['compA', 'compB']">{{c}}</option>    
  </select>
  <component :is="value" />
  </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```